# vb.net intellisense not showing methods

Tags: vb.net, intellisense

why does intellisense does not show some methods in vb.net?

e.g. HttpRequestMessageExtensions class from System.Net.Http is not shown at all.

this is ok with c#

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product item = repository.Get(id);

    if (item == null)
    {
        var message = string.Format("Product with id = {0} not found", id);
        var err = new HttpError(message);
        err["error_sub_code"] = 42;
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
    }
    else
    {
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, item);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: Check if the "All" tab is selected of IntelliSense and not just the "Common" tab.

Comment: There is a work-around:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509543/missing-request-createresponse-in-vb-net-webapi-projects/21164101#21164101

Comment: Thanks Simcha khabinsky.